# sitemaps.xml not working in google app engine or local google sdk but it does work running in django 1.9.7 server

Tags: django, google-app-engine

In the following image on the left side is the **google server** and on the right side is the **django server**:

[image: left **google server** other one is in **django server**]

The google server does not show any logs about it, at first sight, the xml is rendered by the server but it doesn't show the links of the sitemap,

## sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from datetime import datetime


class BasicSitemap(Sitemap):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def items(self):
        return self.names

    def changefreq(self, obj):
        return 'weekly'

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return datetime.now()

    def location(self, obj):
        return reverse(obj)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from sitemap import BasicSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap


sitemaps = {
    'pages': BasicSitemap(['about', 'home', 'team', 'contacto', 'courses', 'services'])
}




urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('apps.home.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.about.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.contact.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.services.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.team.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.client.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('apps.course.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]


def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request):
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Things I've done:

1. run the aplication in different os (linux windows)
2. tried different django versions < 1.9.7

The weird thing about this is that I had a prev version of this site wich was deployed at January this year and it doesn't have that problem, I used logic, but this new app engine seems to work differently.

Any ideas?? [a link to the sitemap page](http://wocom-labs.com/sitemap.xml)

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ django, but the invalid/improperly formatted `<loc/>` tag may suggest a bug somewhere - you're not specifically handling it in your code, it must come from some library you use.

Comment: as I said it works good in pure django server .. it is a google app engine issue

Comment: Is your app using a GAE-provided django and, if so, is that exact version the one running your 'pure django' site? Or is your 'pure django' site version vendored-in/installed into your app?

Comment: It is the same I use down and up GAE becouse I  pushed aside the project...  As a external lib

Comment: Never mind my comment about the `<loc/>` tag - it's just a misleading display, caused by an empty location - the actual content from the page source for the sitemap link you provided is ok: `<loc></loc>`.